# how to access shared object library in function library

Tags: testing, automation, qtp

I am starting with a test automation project which is based on keyword driven framework(to be done with QTP 11).I have gone through QTP basics.Basically all my functions will be present in a function library(associated with my test) and I will be calling them through my actions in test project with different parameters.
For example:
Call Login function from Action1 with username and password parameters.
Now how to access shared object library in function library to access,modify my objects present in shared library?And if the position of objects change,will my script break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a function library from an action you're still in the context of that action. This means that all the object repositories associated with the action (the local OR and any shared ORs) are available.

All you have to do is make sure that all objects used by a function library are in a SOR (shared object repository) and that this SOR is associated with all actions in your test.